# Different results subsetting with column names

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset

I apologize if I'm duplicating a question but I'm a newbie and I couldn't find the answer (probably because I lack the jargon).

I generated a data frame like so:

```
x1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
x2 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
df <- data.frame(x1,x2)

   x1 x2
1  1  a
2  2  b
3  3  c
4  4  d
5  5  e
```

Then I tried to subset conditioning on the first column like this

```
df[df$x1>3, "x2"]
```

The result was as expected

```
[1] d e
```

However when I try

```
df["x1" >3, "x2"]
[1] a b c d e
```

R seems to ignore the conditional statement and returns the whole column x2. Is there a way of evaluating conditional statements (<,>,==) using the column names?

**EDIT:** I think I found the answer partially: R evaluates

```
"some text" > 1000 
[1] TRUE
```

and that explains why I get all the rows.

The question remains: what is a good way of evaluating conditional statements using column names?

Comment: Yes, with `df[df[["x1"]] > 3, "x2"]`.  The expression `"x1" > 3` evaluates to `TRUE`, so in your second try you are doing `df[TRUE, "x2"]` which explains the result

Comment: Thanks so much. That did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't go into a long explanation because I think you'll be able to see the issue clearly with a few examples.  But basically, if you want to use the character data frame names, you will need a construct like this

```
df[df[["x1"]] > 3, "x2"]
# [1] d e
# Levels: a b c d e
```

What was happening with your second try is this

```
"x1" > 3
# [1] TRUE
```

And then basically what you did was this

```
df[TRUE, "x2"]
# [1] a b c d e
# Levels: a b c d e
```

giving all elements.  I would have to look up the reason of exactly why a character is always greater than a number.  I think this reason has been described in detail somewhere around here before.  If I remember correctly it has to do with precedence between classes.  I'll see if I can find it.

Answer (score -1):

Your question could have many answers, especially depending on the context and the type of data you're working with. In this particular case though, you could simply use `df[x1 > 3, "x2"]`.

The first argument is for rows and the second argument is for columns. Essentially, you are saying to return all df rows where x1 is greater than 3. In terms of columns, you want only column x2. You'll get it pretty quickly once you tweak around with the different statements. Hope this helps.

Comment: `df[x1 > 3, "x2"]` will not work with a data.frame. It will with a data.table but that's not what the OP is using. You need the `df$` in `df[df$x1 > 3, "x2"]`

Comment: Also, I think we should always operate on the premise that the vectors used to create the data frame (`x1` and `x2`) will not be available once the data frame (`df`) is created.

Comment: @MrFlick - Thanks, that is an oversight on my part. Weirdly though, I ran the line without `df$` just to ensure it worked, and for some reason, I got the same result. Do you know what is going on?  
`> x1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
> x2 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
> df <- data.frame(x1,x2)
> 
> df[df$x1 > 3, "x2"]
[1] d e
Levels: a b c d e
> 
> df[x1>3, "x2"]
[1] d e
Levels: a b c d e`

Comment: It's because to create this sample data, x1 and x2 were created outside and inside the data frame. This is not usually the case. You want to make sure to subset with the values from the data frame.